# ORMLite : Dao.getEmptyForeignCollection is always returning eager collections

Tags: collections, ormlite

```
public class Account {
    …
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, columnName = "orders")
    ForeignCollection<Order> orders;
    …
}

Account account = new Account();
account.orders = accountDao.getEmptyForeignCollection("orders");
```

I have lazy collection for orders.  But `getEmptyForeginCollection()` is returning an `EagerForeignCollection` object.  Why? is there any reason?  Thanks.

Comment: I added my answer which is that it is this way "by design".  Can you explain why you have a problem with it?  What is the use case?  THanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was done on purpose.  The lazy collections are more complicated since then have underlying DAO reference.  Since you are using the collection so you can call `account.orders.add(order1)` and the like, the idea was that you didn't need the "fake" collection to be lazy.

I do see, however, that since it is a lazy collection, it is unexpected to have another entity add an order for an account and have the `orders` fields *not* see it because it is eager.  I've added the following bug to the list and I'm going to ask the user base if there is any reason not to fix this.

> https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3538474&group_id=297653&atid=1255989